# ¿Cómo obtengo el ranking en una tabla dinámica de Power Bi como la indicada?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo una matriz como la de la imagen en la que muestro las ventas diarias por mes de un grupo de vendedores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder obtener un ranking individual para los días de cada mes, de manera que, por ejemplo, para el mes mostrado de febrero me indicase el ranking solo para esos 4 días (entre 1 y 4). Si desplegamos marzo me mostrase otro ranking, también empezando en 1, para los días contenidos en ese mes, y así sucesivamente con todos los meses y vendedores.

Lo he intentado de varias maneras con la función RANKX y no me ha salido. Cuando genero un ranking solo de vendedores me sale perfectamente utilizando esta medida:

```
RANKX(ALLSELECTED(dimVendedores),[Ventas])
```

El problema viene cuando añado la dimensión de fechas con el escalado de Mes y día. Soy incapaz de hacer lo que describía arriba.

Adjunto modelo de tablas para diferenciar la tabla de hechos de las de dimensiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La medida [Ventas] anterior es simplemente la suma del precio unitario de los productos multiplicado por la cantidad vendida. Algo muy sencillo.

Hay que tener en cuenta que hay una segmentación por año, de ahí que utilice ALLSELECTED en mi fórmula anterior.

¿Alguien puede orientarme cómo podría obtener el ranking de las ventas diarias de cada mes y cada vendedor?

Para concluir, os hago un esquema rápido de lo que necesito obtener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería muchísimo vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he logrado. Ha costado, pero finalmente y tras mucho indagar, he logrado obtener lo que perseguía.

Comparto por si a alguien le es de ayuda:

```
Ranking = 
VAR v =
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( [ventas] ),
        BLANK (),
        RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( dimVendedores ), [Ventas] )
    )
VAR m =
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( dimFechas[Mes] ),
        IF (
            ISBLANK ( [Ventas] ),
            BLANK (),
            RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( dimFechas[Mes], dimFechas[N.Mes] ), [Ventas] )
        )
    )
VAR d =
    IF (
        ISINSCOPE ( dimFechas[dia] ),
        IF (
            ISBLANK ( [Ventas] ),
            BLANK (),
            RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( dimFechas[dia] ), [Ventas] )
        )
    )
RETURN
    COALESCE ( d, m, v )
```

Y como veis el resultado es el esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]